# Index of a private domain delegated to Salesforce give 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, cloudpagesurl

We already delegated a private domain to Salesforce Marketing Cloud

what is happening is that in the index we are getting the following error

Server Error
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

[image]

All the pages with a sitekey is working properlly
ie:
http://privatedomaindelegated.com/sitekey  is working fine  but in the root is getting the error
http://privatedomaindelegated.com  i where I got the error

Even I checked a private domain with a SAP  and getting the same error

We asked to Salesforce for a redirection or the possibility to create like an index pages in order don't show this error message and they said that it is no possible

Somebody here know a possible troubleshooting for this.
I really appreciate any answer

Comment: You can't host a "/index.html" for your Sender Authentication Package's domain and have SFMC automatically redirect requests for "http://mySAPdomain" to that page, if that's what you're trying to do? Support are correct, sometimes.

Comment: Thanks Macca
I really appreciate your answer

Just I had a call with Salesforce team and You are right. Salesforce has not support that feature for SAP or even private domains delegated to Salersforce

Apparently they are working to support it next year

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you upvote this idea: [CloudPages default index page](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E9xVQAS)

But this is currently how these domains work